# Python: How do I search through an array of objects

Tags: python

How do I search through an array of objects, and return and print all of its relevant properties based on the ID that the user has input.
PS: You can just ignore most of the code and just scroll to the last part of the code which is relevant.

TheArray is the array which the objects are being stored into

Example Code:

```
class User():
    def __init__(self,Number,Name):
        ID = Number
        User = Name
    def Get_ID(self):
        return Number
class Telephone(User):
    def __init__(self,Number,Name,TelephoneNumber):
        User.__init__(self,Number,Name)
        Telephone = TelephoneNumber
    def Get_Telephone(self):
        return Telephone

TheArray = []
Phone = Telephone(1, "Marc", 8888)
TheArray.append(Telephone)
Phone = Telephone(1, "Jack", 9999)
TheArray.append(Telephone)
```

Comment: Rather than making us scroll through loads of useless code, post a minimal, reproducible, example that demonstrates your issue as succinctly as possible. And while you're at it, please ask a specific question about the code.

Comment: You could make getter functions that will get the properties to print.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `__dict__` to get object's property. Like below:

```
counter = 0
TheArray = []
while Counter < 18:
    VehicleClass = Vehicle("Red Sports Car", "RSC13", 15.00, Counter, "Car", 3.3, 12.1, 0.08)
    TheArray.append(VehicleClass)
    Counter = Counter + 1
print(TheArray)

for obj in TheArray:
    print(obj.__dict__)
```

Hope it would help you..!!